# Do any C++ compilers remove if statements that always hold the same answer when inlining?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

If I have for example the following function:

```
void foo(DoThisSometimes, DoThisAlways)
{
  if (DoThisSometimes == 1)
    {
      //Do stuff
    }
  //Do other stuff
{
```

And an inlined piece of code calls this function with `DoThisSometimes` as 0, are there any compilers that would remove this part of the code from the inlined function:

```
if (DoThisSometimes == 1)
    {
      //Do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Probably most compilers do that.

Comment: If the compiler inlines `foo` when it is called with a literal value for `DoThisSometimes`, it will (probably) remove the branch (and for values `!= 1`, the code inside the `if`).

Comment: Most compilers will *probably* do that with optimizations enabled, especially when they apply "global optimizations".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A decent compiler certainly should do that optimisation, and GCC does. The following source:

```
#include <cstdio>

inline void foo(bool maybe)
{
    if (maybe) {
        printf("Maybe\n");
    }
    printf("Always\n");
}

int main()
{
    foo(true);
    foo(false);
}
```

compiles (with optimisation `-O3`) to:

```
0000000000400410 <main>:
  400410:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400414:   bf e4 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005e4,%edi
  400419:   e8 d2 ff ff ff          callq  4003f0 <puts@plt>
  40041e:   bf ea 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005ea,%edi
  400423:   e8 c8 ff ff ff          callq  4003f0 <puts@plt>
  400428:   bf ea 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005ea,%edi
  40042d:   e8 be ff ff ff          callq  4003f0 <puts@plt>
  400432:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400434:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400438:   c3                      retq   
  400439:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
```

calling `puts` three times, unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most likely. If the compiler can figure out what the value is, it will often remove all or parts of an if-statement.

By parts of, I mean if you do:

```
 if (DoThisSometimes == 1 || foo == 0)
```

the compiler can perhaps remove `DoThisSometimes==1`, but not the `foo == 0` part, as `foo` may not have a known value at the inlining point.

Bear in mind that this is compiler implementation details, so the compiler is not GUARANTEED to remove the statement, and it most certainly will not if it can't figure out what the value is. It may also decide not to inline a function when it has the if-statement, because it thinks the function is too long, and then when the if-statement is gone, it would be OK to inline. So whilst you can expect this to happen, you should certainly not RELY on it, if it's super-critical - in that case, make two functions, one for "DoThisSometimes == 1" and one for "DoThisSometimes != 1".